# Widget for facebook problem

Tags: html, flash, iframe

I've just finished making a widget for use on facebook, through Clearsprings. This is the second one we've made and the first one was fine. This time I ran into some problems when trying to embed it into facebook.

The problem is the SWF won't embed, so I've gone for HTML option. However this puts it in an iFrame which then sits on top of the facebook layout, menus etc. Obviously not intended behavhiour, and it also stops the user from clicking add.

Any ideas on what I could do to get around this?

EDIT: Solved, the issue with the embedding was a maxium document height. Re-did 600 instead of 800px high and it was fine.

Comment: If you solved it, feel free to answer your own question and mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: or if you don't think others would benefit from your solution, delete the question.

Comment: thanks, im new to this site and appreciate pointers like this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it appears that the Max Size of 800px is a little close to the bone. I wouldn't recommend using their recommend height.

Reducing the height is a good idea.

I understand that iFrame's sit above anything as z-index doesn't effect them.

Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the issue with the embedding was a maxium document height. Re-did 600 instead of 800px high and it was fine.